# Updated Windows 8, tried to fix with Boot Repair and can't pass GNU GRUB screen

Tags: grub2, windows, updates, boot-repair

I'm having a hard time now with my laptop. I have an ASUS X501 with Windows8 preloaded and I decided to install Ubuntu Studio last year. Everything was great, I was able to choose to boot into Ubuntu or Windows when I turned on the computer.

You know how Windows is, so my brother used the laptop the other day and "accidentally" updated some components of Windows, which screwed the boot menu and always booted directly into Windows.

I had no way to run Ubuntu, so I searched for help and I found that I needed to run Ubuntu through a Live USB (my laptop doesn't come with DVD unit) and then inside Ubuntu I should run boot repair.

I downloaded the ISO and created the USB live stick, managed to boot into it, ran Boot-Repair through terminal and followed the recommended option to repair it. It said it was ready and I should reboot the computer.

So I did but I got into this screen.

```
GNU GRUB version 2.00-19ubuntu2.1

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible
command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions

grub>
```

and now I cant get past it. I can't boot into Windows, I can't boot Ubuntu, I cant boot live USB..

I've been trying to make some changes on the BIOS to choose the boot properties, disabling and enabling options but nothing helps.

After I ran Boot-repair, I got a message of the log of the repair process, and this is it:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6823916/

Thanks for your help

---

UPDATE

Ok, Now I'm able to boot the Live USB stick. It seems that the memory on the USB 3.0 was not being recognized, I put it on other normal USB port and worked. It seems to me it has to do with some UEFI things. Since this is the only thing that can boot, the other options Windows bootloader and ubuntustudio doesn't say anything about "UEFI" at the boot menu, only the usb stick..

I have ran again boot-repair and played around on the advanced options enabling and disabling options but nothing changes..

For me, it has to do with something that Windows and ubunu partitions need to be set up as UEFI, and they currently are not..

No matter which option I select it will take me back to the GRUB GNU screen, unless I select UEFI Kingston which is the live USB..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did this. Better to undo it. This is for those systems that only boot Windwows from UEFI menu, but then can only boot Windows backed up file bkpbootmgfw.efi from grub menu.
WinEFI detected. Do you want to activate [Backup and rename Windows EFI files]? yes (if any choice fails, please retry with the other)

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

You show grub installed to protective MBR. Were you booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode from UEFI/BIOS menu and Windows from UEFI menu in UEFI mode?

After undo of rename confirm if you can boot ubuntu entry in UEFI menu. Windows will also work from UEFI menu after undo of rename.